# Set default content for target div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

If this is my code, how do i set page1.html to show by default on page load?

Thanks in advance.

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function swapContent(targetID, url) {
        var target = document.getElementById(targetID);
 
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open('GET', url, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajax.readyState == 4) {
                target.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send(null);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="javascript: void();" onclick="swapContent('searchDiv', 'page1.html');">First</a> |
            <a href="javascript: void();" onclick="swapContent('searchDiv', 'page2.html');">Second</a> |
            <a href="javascript: void();" onclick="swapContent('searchDiv', 'page3.html');">Third</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="searchDiv" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; overflow: scroll;">Please select one...</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the onload event handler to thebody element:

```
 <body onload ="swapContent('searchDiv', 'page1.html');">
    ....

 </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be loaded by javascript:

```
<body onload="swapContent('searchDiv', 'page1.html');">
```

Answer (score 1):

How about calling `swapContent('searchDiv', 'page1.html');` in `onload` of the `body` tag?

Answer (score 1):

either put it in the onload event or depending on your framework you could include page1 inside the div in django it's

```
<div>{% include 'page1.html' %}</div>
```